# Entity Framework change name of generated many to many table

Tags: c#, sql, .net, entity-framework, datatable

I have an issue where the generated table for a many to many relation is not what I want it to be. Is there any way to tell Entity Framework what to name this table? The solution works, I'm just annoyed by how it chose to name this table.

My Db sets

```
public DbSet<Book> Books { get; set; }
public DbSet<BookCategory> BookCategories { get; set; }
```

My models

Models/Book.cs

```
class Book
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Author { get; set; }
    public int Price { get; set; }
    public int Amount { get; set; }
    public int BookCategoryId { get; set; }
    public List<BookCategory> BookCategories { get; set; }
}
```

Models/BookCategory.cs

```
class BookCategory
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Book> Books { get; set; }
}
```

How the table looks in SQL Server Express:

[image: Picture showing the generated name of the join table being "BookBookCategory"]

So I want to change the table ended up named "BookBookCategory" to something more relevant, how do I approach this? :)

**EDIT**

Sorry I meant that this was a many to many relationship, not a one to many. And i want the table to be named something like "BookCategoryId".

Comment: Do you have a name in mind? Keep in mind that any customisation will incur a maintenance overhead so just consider whether it's really worth doing this

Comment: You probably want this to be a *many-to-many relationship*. It's to you to decide if you want to have this with of without an explicit junction class in your class model.

Comment: Oh right! My bad! Its a Many-to-Many relationship! I got those two mixed up. I would maybe want the table to be called something like "BookCategoryId" i think

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [`UsingEntity`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key#join-entity-type-configuration) from the Fluent API to configure your entity type.

So, in your `OnModelCreating` you could have this:

```
internal class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public MyContext(DbContextOptions<MyContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    public DbSet<Book> Books { get; set; }
    public DbSet<BookCategory> Tags { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder
            .Entity<Book>()
            .HasMany(b => b.BookCategories)
            .WithMany(bc => bc.Book)
            .UsingEntity(j => j.ToTable("YourCustomName"));
    }
}
```